# How to show the list of data at the time of search operation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to show the list of data at the time of search operation. By default the list will be empty. If any search occurred that corresponding data will show in the grid. If no search occurred the list will be empty. How to achieve this using angular 6. Getting list of data i am using *ngFor. By default it show all the data in the list. But in my scenario data shows at the time of search.

```
serach: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="queryString">

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>first Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let item of data | filter:queryString:'firstname'; let i = index">
<td>{{item.firstname}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In  your `filter` component check `queryString` length based on that return items.like follows. if the lenght is `0` just return empty array

```
   if ( !queryString || queryString.length==0) return [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a filter

```
import { Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
 name: 'searchfilter'
})

@Injectable()
export class SearchFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
 transform(items: any[], searchInTable: any): any[] {
   if (searchInTable === undefined) {
     return null;
   }
   return items.filter(function(x) {
    var add = x.firstname.toLowerCase().includes(searchInTable.toLowerCase());

    return (add);
   });
 }
}
```

in HTML

```
serach: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchInTable">

<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>first Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let item of data | searchfilter:searchInTable; let i = index">
<td>{{item.firstname}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

in app.module

```
import { SearchFilterPipe } from '../shared/filters';
declarations: [HomeComponent, SearchFilterPipe],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using NgIf for conditionally hiding the DOM element.

Give NgIf condition to table element, checking the length of ngmodel of input search field.

`serach: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="queryString">
 <table *ngIf="queryString.length !=0">
 </table>`